# True, false, background process in Bash

Tags: bash, wget, zenity

Final result of the finite tasks in the background:

```
( wget google.com && zenity --info || zenity --error ) & PID=$!
...if ... kill $PID ...zenity ...
```

Why will not he act? How should it be good?

[edit:] Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details regarding your problem?

Answer (score 1):

With what you posted, `wget` get started in the background, but `zenity` doesn't, it runs right after `wget` has been started. So it has no chance at all of getting `wget`'s return value: `wget` hasn't completed yet!

Try something like:

```
( wget google.com  && zenity --info || zenity --error ) &
PID=$!
if ... kill $PID ...zenity ...
```

Comment: As early as I did, I did not work. I jumped out the error:
> kill: (8524) - No such process

ps-f displays:
> arney   8526  8061  0 10:14 pts/0    00:00:00 wget google.com

The Fedora is ok. I do not understand Ubuntu. I have to remove and install Fedora. Thank you again.

Comment: Changing distributions for that is simply not a good idea, you'll get the exact same behavior on Fedora (or SuSE, or Gentoo, or...) Are you sure you put the parenthesis and & exactly as above?

Comment: I want to achieve:
>>> ( ( wget google.com && true > files || echo "no" > files ) & echo > PID ) | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close || kill "`cat PID`" ; [ ! -s files ] && zenity --info || zenity --error <<<

Is unable to otherwise free parentheses.

Comment: Sometimes the process can die just before you try to kill it.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes wget is different id than the variable $PID, np. wget = 1250, $PID = 1252. Then there is no chance to kill the wget.

Comment: The pid you get should be the pid of the subshell that runs wget if you use the syntax I put above. That shouldn't die before wget has died, and should kill wget if you kill it.